# Adjust size of headline background-color using CSS

Tags: css, text, background-color, word-wrap, heading

I've been fiddling with both h1 and hyperlink background-color for a few hours,
I'm struggling to control the attribute well enough to achieve the desired style.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to control the height of the background-color highlight but don't think this is possible with pure css. I'd like the highlight to sit snug to the type as illustrated here:

https://jsfiddle.net/j6x3uz5z/

```
a.menu:hover {
color:#fff;
display:inline-block;
background-color:#f90703;
padding-right:6px;
text-decoration:none;   
}
```

Though this is the look i'm trying to achieve, the problem is that the highlight is running to the full width of the container when the window is resized and the copy wraps around.

This can be fixed by changing the display setting to 'inline'. The problem with this however is that the size of the background-color element expands causing a clash with the type above and below:

https://jsfiddle.net/xzLkmeq0/

```
a.menu:hover {
color:#fff;
display:inline;
background-color:#f90703;
padding-right:6px;
text-decoration:none;   
}
```

Unfortunately I can't find a middle ground. I like the snug fitting rendering that the 'inline-block' setting allows, but wish to retain the wrapping background-color achieved through 'inline' display.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated...

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding top/bottom padding and/or line-height?

Comment: Your `line-height` is causing this. Remove it.

Comment: Hey, I've tried adjusting padding, the problem there is that I don't want to add padding, I need to reduce if anything.

Comment: Line-height is causing the crashing yes. When display is set to 'inline' anyway. I want the leading to be this tight so unfortunately no fix there. Unless I can adjust the leading elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Try:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOjMYO

```
h2 {
    display:inline;
    font-size:96px;
    padding:0;
    color:#FFF;
    border:0;
    font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:-3px;
    word-spacing:-15px;
    font-weight:600;
    font-style:normal;
}

a:link,a:active,a:visited,a:hover,a.menu:link,a.menu:visited,a.header:link,a.header:active,a.header:visited,a.header:hover {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none
}

a.menu:active {
    color:#f90703;
    text-decoration:none
}

a.menu span { 
    position: relative
}

a.menu:hover {
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#f90703;
    padding-right:6px;
    text-decoration:none;   
}

a.link {
    position:relative;
    color:#000;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-right:3px;
    padding-top:50px;
    margin:0;
    text-decoration:none
}

a.link:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#f90703
}

.homemenu {
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    z-index:20;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, I need to keep the leading as tight as it is in the fiddles. line-height needs to stay as is. Thanks.